# Symfony2 field order in database table

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have generated 2 entities in my bundle and then using `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` I recreate database schema. The order of fields that I have defined in the entities does not match the order of fields in the database table. Is there a way to control/define order in which fields are listed in the database table?

Thanks,
Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a problem; If you have generated the schema first then you updated it, the new fields will be just appended to current columns.

Furthermore you can find this different order for columns which has relationship which will be appended, too (on the generation time). In fact it does not create any issue; but if it's important to you, you can change the arrangement through one of the DataBase Management Tools (e.g. phpMyAdmin)

Comment: Can you do it programmatically (in the entity class) rather than updating table structure?

Comment: Unfortunately Symfony does not handle that, the `alter table` is the code but cannot be used to force it update your schema through Symfony